# Model Auto Increment Number Issue.. After 1,000 Records

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

Please help me to fix this issue as i am getting it from today morning... After doing some research i have found the issue...

I have a table called... "fmb_form_item_answer"

> currently this table is.. having 1079 records
>   Name of the Model is... "FmbFormItemAnswer"

the issue is, after reaching 999th record.. when i access model->id it gives a text instead of int... as 1,002

for example..

when when model->id = 1079, it generates... 1,079 (with comma after 1)

I was able to figure this out after checking the DB logs... below is what i found..

```
2013-08-19 18:59:53 EST ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1,079"
2013-08-19 18:59:53 EST STATEMENT: SELECT * FROM "fmb_form_item_answer" WHERE submission_id=$1
```

please can some expert help me to resolve this issue. its a coming up from a production server.. so any quick help is greatly appreciated...

i tried... this way too....
setting a rule in model....

```
array('id', 'numerical'),
```

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: what is the table field definition

Comment: It's a _bigserial_
=============================
`CREATE TABLE fmb_form_submission
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  form_id bigint NOT NULL,
  date_added timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT pk_fmb_form_submission PRIMARY KEY (id ),
  CONSTRAINT fk_fmb_form_submission_fmb_form FOREIGN KEY (form_id)
      REFERENCES fmb_form (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)`

Comment: if you query manually do you get a output with digits groupped

Comment: here the id not seems to be AUTO_INCREMENT,so you are inserting it in the insert query,May be you are using number_format() or some functions in inserting id please have a look at the insert query.

Comment: @DevZer0 I have added a Screenshot for your question========

and this query works fine....!========
`SELECT * FROM "fmb_form_item_answer" WHERE submission_id=1079`

Comment: @Reshil in PostgreSQL AUTO_INCREMENT is implemented using "Sequences".
I just checked... it is there!

Comment: @ShareekAhamed Serial Types also Doing the same job.(smallserial, serial and bigserial) will create a sequence behind the scenes.. for more details go here
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plese check weather u have number_format() php function enabled somewhere.. if so that could be the reason...

If only one parameter is given, number will be formatted without decimals, but with a comma (",") between every group of thousands.

ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php